# Export data from google analytics attribution model

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, export-to-csv

is there a way to export the data from google analytics Attribution Model comparison tool? I'm searching through all the dimensions an measures but i was unable to find the correct measure.

Is this data available through Core API?
Is there a combination of measures to calculate the different models?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's MCF (Multiple Channel Funnel) API:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/

The model you can use seems to be limited (Only First and Last) but at least you can export your funnel path and built your own attribution much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have asked google for an answer, they don't have this developed yet but there is an open request ticket for it, it could take a few months. I will keep track of this. To get the exact same dimension and metrics, bigquery can do the job.