# How to pull conversion numbers using a different attribution model?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, attribution

This is for one of our clients, who runs GA360.

I'm wondering if it's possible to pull goal completion numbers through the API using a different attribution model than Google's standard 'last non direct click'? Specifically, we are looking to pull numbers using the data-driven model, ideally with a 90-day lookback window.

Thanks,

John

Comment: The attribution should be calculated after the data, have you tried already [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3264076?hl=en) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export data from google analytics attribution model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241967/export-data-from-google-analytics-attribution-model)

Comment: @F.Leone yes, the DDA model has been set up. I just need to export conversion numbers using the API?